# Write to Logs in Python with Inline Message

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, logging, aws-lambda

## Problem

I am developing lambda functions and in my code, I have multiple lines that look something along the lines like the following snippets.

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

#dummy example 1
logger.info("pre-formatted data")
logger.info(data)


#dummy example 2
logger.info("jsonData")
logger.info(json.dumps(jsonData)))
```

## Question

I was hoping to do something along the lines of instead:

```
#desired output
logger.info("JSON Data", json.dumps(jsonData))
```

Comment: `logger.info(f"JSON Data: {json.dumps(jsonData)}")` should work. Your log output will be found under CloudWatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own logger class in a way that behaves similarly to the default logger, but using `*args` to take an arbitrarily long number of parameters

See example:

```py
import logging


class Logger:
    def __init__(self, name, level):
        logging.basicConfig(level=level)
        self._logger = logging.getLogger(name)

    def debug(self, *args):
        for arg in args:
            self._logger.debug(arg)

    def info(self, *args):
        for arg in args:
            self._logger.info(arg)

    def warning(self, *args):
        for arg in args:
            self._logger.warning(arg)

    def error(self, *args):
        for arg in args:
            self._logger.error(arg)


logger = Logger("test_logger", level=logging.INFO)
logger.info("logline1", "logline2", "logline3")
```

The output will be:

```
INFO:test_logger:logline1
INFO:test_logger:logline2
INFO:test_logger:logline3
```

Which can be adjusted by passing a format to the `logging.basicConfig`

Comment: I want to be able to pass in custom messages with each time I call the logger.info for example like logger.info("updating the data", updateData), or like logger.info("pre-update", data) and I would want it to log "updating the data" :  [a,b,c,d]. Sort of like how console.log("message", data) or console.WriteLine works

Comment: In this case you can replace the inner part of the loops with `print(" ".join([str(a) for a in args]))`